# Azure ARM template issue

Tags: azure

I am deploying my infrastructure using an ARM template. I have done this more than once. This time I am getting an error I just cannot figure out.

```
Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets' requires '2' resource name argument(s).
```

So I need the subnet id and I have a well-formed resource id string (I thought)

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/', 
parameters('virtualNetworks_CloudEngine_RG_vnet_name'), 
parameters('subnets_default_name'))]
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I have incorrect.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: this looks 100% legit, can you share the template?

Comment: How do I upload it to StackOverflow?

Comment: just upload it to pastebin.com\paste.ee\github.com\whatever and share the link

Comment: Here is the template https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoXD5g8lRKKSkdRO7SwnflQ1_2lbLg

Comment: error outputs in ARM Templates are reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaly misleading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is on line 171

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('subnets_default_name'))]",
```

you forgot to input vnet name.

Comment: Thanks so much guess I was not going far enough down the template